# Formatted (HTML) user signature at Request Tracker?

Tags: request-tracker

Is there a way to use formatted user signature at Request Tracker? I already set Templates to use text/html messages. Tried to add HTML tags to signature, but < is translated as &lt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with the current code in RT 4.2. You can see it in lines 69-76 of 
https://github.com/bestpractical/rt/blob/stable/share/html/Elements/MessageBox

For security reasons, the authors escape dangerous characters as HTML entities.

You can modify this behaviour by copying this file to `local/html/Elements/` and commenting out those lines, but **THIS IS A BIG SECURITY RISK**. You are allowing your users to include code in your RT web site. Basically, you are creating a persistent XSS vulnerability [1] exploitable by any of your users (if the output is not escaped later).

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Persistent